# Selenium can't find dynamicly generated content on Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem accessing content on **ChromeDriver**.

In **Firefox** simple workaround helped:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
```

Unfortunatelly for **Chrome** I get **NoSuchFrameException**.

I think my elements are created by:

```
        <section class="main-section">
            <!-- uiView:  --><div ui-view="" class="ng-scope"><div ng-controller="externalPageController as ctrl" ng-init="init()" class="ng-scope">
                <!-- ngIf: methods.isDefined() --><div ng-if="methods.isDefined()" class="ng-scope">

                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="text/html" ng-attr-data="{{objectUrl}}" data="/alert-app"></object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
                </div><!-- end ngIf: methods.isDefined() -->
                </div></div>
        </section>
```

**"main-section"** is the inner-most element I can access.

Is there some way to get elements that are inside **"main-section"**?

Waiting for them doesn't work, I got timeout.

Comment: open chrome and check if the frame is present by inspecting the HTML (F12). Could be possible that the frame is not present in chrome or may take a longer time to load

Comment: when I try to inspect element only this HTML is displayed. When I click second time to inspect full HTML is loaded. It does not depend on time, but on number of clicks.

Comment: that is strange .. Does the full HTML contain frame? Is this behavior same in all browsers ? On which element are you clicking to inspect element ?

Comment: @Striker There are no frames, divs only. In firefox when I click on "Inspect element" it gets to full HTML. I am trying to inspect row of table witch is inside "main-section".

Comment: @Striker For Firefox selenium driver it also doesn't work correctly, I have to use this hack with switching to frame, without it Selenium also does not see all elements.

Comment: then why does the switch to frame code work in FF if there is no frame .. IS it possible that you can share the full HTML ?

Comment: now I see that FF interprets it as frame, but there is no <frame> or <iframe> tag in html, I suspect it is this <object>

Comment: @Striker Now I got this - I had to switch_to_frame using this object element and it works fine now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can post this answer and accept the same so that the question is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My page was built with frames, but they were not in `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tag, but as **`<object>`**.

I had to find this element and pass to `driver.switch_to_frame(object_element)`, now **ChromeDriver** works fine.